# Using cucumber android in unit testing "test" directory and not in "androidTest" for integration testing

Tags: android, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to use cucumber-android for integration testing in "test" directory. All the code samples/examples I found use "androidTest" directory and UI tests.

I'm looking to use cucumber for integration testing of several different components, without UI, to start with.

For example, I want to integration test viewModel. Here is my sample code.

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = ["src/test/assets/features"],
    glue = ["com.example.mysteps"]
)
class MyIntegrationTest : BaseIntegrationTest() {

    @Test
    fun `runCucumber`() {
        Cucumber(CheckoutIntegrationTest::java).run() 
    }
}
```

And my steps class is

```
class Steps {   

    @Given("^The vendor is selected for delivery type$")
    fun `test given`() {
        println("### given")
    }

    @When("^Time picker is loaded$")
    fun `test when`()
        println("### when")
    }

    @Then("^The vendor is available with different timeslots$")
    fun `test then`() {
        println("### then")
    }
}
```

There are a few questions.

1. How can I inject the objects into Steps class from my dagger object graph? We are using Anvil and not pico-container.
2. What are various ways of running a cucumber test? I'm currently running from Android studio's run button.